# Error in php (Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0)

Tags: php

I've got this problem, so i run my php  code and it logins sucesfully but i still get this alert.
My login.php is:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$sql = ("select email from Empregados where email='" . $email . "' and password='".$password."'");

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[] = $row['email'];
    echo "<p>Login com sucesso</p>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Dados incorretos</p>";
}
?>
```

> Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: `$_SESSION[] = $row['email'];` You should be setting a string key.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Please don't use `md5()` for password storyge. Use `password_verify()` instead

Comment: Where is `session_start()`

Comment: @JonStirling so how should I use it then, can you give me an example ?

Comment: `$_SESSION['some_sort_of_descriptive_name'][] = $row['email'];` After initialising the array.

Comment: @JonStirling if i do that i have an error ("Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in")

Comment: That sounds like you're already using that key to store a string, use a different one.

Comment: @JonStirling Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP session storage mechanism was originally built around "registering" variables, so the keys in `$_SESSION` must be names that could be treated as variables in their own right.

This means that `$_SESSION[]` or `$_SESSION[22]` is invalid, because it wouldn't be a valid variable name, `$_SESSION[]` is invalid as well.

The solution is either to use a prefix on your session variables **(e.g. $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];)**

Comment: You solved the unsolvable! Thank you!